# Passing parameters to timer event

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create an animation that moves some images across the canvas in my applications layout.

The canvas is named `layout` which belongs to the main window and the timer is calling the event `Animation.Clouds(layout, 1)`. When attempting this I am getting an error regarding the object is owned by another thread. This has left me to believe that the cause is the timer not being able to pass the context of `layout`, causing the error.

How would I solve this issue and pass `layout` to the timer in order for the animation to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) instead, it fire a tick in dispatcher thread it is created

Comment: Don't worry, i will be doing but it wont let me for a set amount of time which is fairly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can **ONLY** update a UI element, when you are on the UI thread.  The Timer event gets invoke on a different thread.

In Windows.Forms you can use `BeginInvoke`.  I'm sure WPF has something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i am new to C#. ArsenMkrt's method seems to have done the job but thanks all the same.

Comment: No worries, as I commented @ArsenMkrt has a better answer.  I'm not a WPF dude.